# Parsing XML data to Core Data

Tags: ios, xml, swift, core-data

I'm trying to fetch data from an online xml file and put it inside my core data.

I can successfully retrieve the data and I can even put it inside core data, but it seems that only the last retrieved feed is stored.

[Here](http://paste.debian.net/hidden/99aa077e) is the example of the xml file I'm trying to retrieve.

Parser code example:

```
    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("question") {
            if !xml_tmp1.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(xml_tmp1, forKey: "text")
            }
            if !xml_tmp2.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(xml_tmp2, forKey: "answer0")
            }

            if !xml_tmp3.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(xml_tmp3, forKey: "answer1")
            }

            if !xml_tmp4.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(xml_tmp4, forKey: "answer2")
            }

            if !xml_tmp5.isEqual(nil) {
                elements.setObject(xml_tmp5, forKey: "answer3")
            }
            tmp_xml.addObject(elements)
        }
    }
```

Core Data code example:

```
    func temp_func() {
        var n: Int = tmp_xml.count
        var i: Int = 0

        var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

        var tmp = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Questions", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject

        while (i != br) {
            tmp.setValue(tmp_xml.objectAtIndex(i).valueForKey("text"), forKey: "question")
            tmp.setValue(tmp_xml.objectAtIndex(i).valueForKey("answer0"), forKey: "answer_1")
            tmp.setValue(tmp_xml.objectAtIndex(i).valueForKey("answer1"), forKey: "answer_2")
            tmp.setValue(tmp_xml.objectAtIndex(i).valueForKey("answer2"), forKey: "answer_3")
            tmp.setValue(tmp_xml.objectAtIndex(i).valueForKey("answer3"), forKey: "answer_4")

            i++
        }

        context.save(nil)
    }
```

So basically, I should get three new entries in my core data, but only the last one ( 15 * 7 question ) is stored.

Comment: Just a guess: if I'm not mistaken, in your `while` loop, you're setting values over and over *for the same keys on the same object*. `tmp.setValue(tmp_xml.objectAtIndex(0).valueForKey("text"), forKey: "question")` then `tmp.setValue(tmp_xml.objectAtIndex(1).valueForKey("text"), forKey: "question")` : `tmp` will only have the last iteration (1) for the "question" key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think U just create one entry in U core data and U setValue than save it. So only last Entry save in the core data. U can just create entry in the while loop. like this see it can work ?

```
func temp_func() {
    var n: Int = tmp_xml.count
    var i: Int = 0

    var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!


    while (i != br) {
        var tmp = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Questions", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! NSManagedObject
        tmp.setValue(tmp_xml.objectAtIndex(i).valueForKey("text"), forKey: "question")
        tmp.setValue(tmp_xml.objectAtIndex(i).valueForKey("answer0"), forKey: "answer_1")
        tmp.setValue(tmp_xml.objectAtIndex(i).valueForKey("answer1"), forKey: "answer_2")
        tmp.setValue(tmp_xml.objectAtIndex(i).valueForKey("answer2"), forKey: "answer_3")
        tmp.setValue(tmp_xml.objectAtIndex(i).valueForKey("answer3"), forKey: "answer_4")

        i++
    }

    context.save(nil)
}
```

Comment: The xml file returns values containing tabs and new lines, so how can I remove them to get the bare string value. I have tried the following but it doesn't works, thanks. tmp.setValue(tmp_xml.objectAtIndex(i).valueForKey("answer0".stringByReplac‌​ingOccurrencesOfString("\n\t", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil), forKey: "answer_1")

Comment: Ok, I have resolved this. 

I didn't realize that the function _stringByReplac‌​ingO‌​ccurrencesOfString()_ returns a new string instead of modifying the existing one.

Thanks to everyone for the help.